# Lagging when scroll in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I am animating the Toolbar in order to hide/show. I am using following CoordinatorLayout Behavior :

```
public abstract class QuickHideBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    private static final int DIRECTION_UP = 1;
    private static final int DIRECTION_DOWN = -1;

    /* Tracking last threshold crossed */
    private int mScrollTrigger;

    private ObjectAnimator mAnimator;

    private View mRecyclerView;

    protected abstract void directionUpScrolling(View recyclerView);

    protected abstract void directionDownScrolling(View recyclerView);

    protected abstract float getTargetHideValue(ViewGroup parent, View target);

    //Required to instantiate as a default behavior
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public QuickHideBehavior() {
    }

    //Required to attach behavior via XML
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public QuickHideBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    //Called before a nested scroll event. Return true to declare interest
    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                       View child, View directTargetChild, View target,
                                       int nestedScrollAxes, int type) {
        //We have to declare interest in the scroll to receive further events
        return (nestedScrollAxes & ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) != 0;
    }

    //Called after the scrolling child handles the fling
    @Override
    public boolean onNestedFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                 View child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY,
                                 boolean consumed) {
        if(mRecyclerView == null) {
            mRecyclerView = target.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        }
        //We only care when the target view is already handling the fling
        if (consumed) {
            if (velocityY > 0 && mScrollTrigger != DIRECTION_UP) {
                mScrollTrigger = DIRECTION_UP;
                restartAnimator(child, getTargetHideValue(coordinatorLayout, child));
                directionUpScrolling(mRecyclerView);

            } else if (velocityY < 0 && mScrollTrigger != DIRECTION_DOWN) {
                mScrollTrigger = DIRECTION_DOWN;
                restartAnimator(child, 0f);
                directionDownScrolling(mRecyclerView);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Helper Methods */

    //Helper to trigger hide/show animation
    private void restartAnimator(View target, float value) {
        if (mAnimator != null) {
            mAnimator.cancel();
            mAnimator = null;
        }

        mAnimator = ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(target, View.TRANSLATION_Y, value)
                .setDuration(250);
        mAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

And there is a child class for AppBar :

```
public class QuickHideAppBarBehavior extends QuickHideBehavior {

    private int actionBarHeight;

    //Required to instantiate as a default behavior
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public QuickHideAppBarBehavior() {
    }

    //Required to attach behavior via XML
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public QuickHideAppBarBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // Calculate ActionBar height
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        actionBarHeight = context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true) ?
                TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()) :
                (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_recycler_view_spacing);
    }

    @Override
    protected float getTargetHideValue(ViewGroup parent, View target) {
        return -target.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void directionUpScrolling(View recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void directionDownScrolling(View recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setPadding(0, actionBarHeight, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

When a new instance of application get created for the first time and there is no instance of app in recent app, it is lagging a little bit at the first scroll but then there is no lagging at all later. When I destroy application instance by clicking on back button and start the app again, there is no lagging, but when I remove the app from recent apps and start the app again, it is lagging a little bit just in the first scroll.
(it happens in Samsung Galaxy s9)

Addenda : When I test in Google pixel2, there is no lagging at all.

Full source code can be found here : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/Contacts/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/contact

Problem could be in my Adapter that I do a heavy work in UI thread  : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/Contacts/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/contact/ui/ContactsAdapter.java

But if I do a heavy work in main thread, why it just happens at start and not later?